# Installing RCurl in R 3.5.0 on Centos 6 - libicui18n.so.58 not found

Tags: r, rcurl

Running R 3.5.0 on CentOS 6.5

I have downloaded RCurl from CRAN, extracted and attempted to install:

```
/share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/bin/R CMD INSTALL RCurl
```

yum install libcurl-devel indicated that the latest version is already installed.

Full log below, but this is the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RCurl' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
     unable to load shared object '/share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/lib64/R/library/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
      libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However it would appear that libicui18n.so.58 is available

```
locate libicui18n.so.58
/state/partition1/apps/anaconda2/lib/libicui18n.so.58
/state/partition1/apps/anaconda2/pkgs/icu-58.2h9c2bf20_1/lib/libicui18n.so.58
```

I have taken a look at other forums, and they suggest that it is a failure to locate the curl-config file; which it is finding at /share/apps/anaconda2/bin/curl-config in my case.

Any advice on how I can install RCurl greatly appreciated.

Full log:

```
* installing to library '/share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/lib64/R/library'
* installing *source* package 'RCurl' ...
** package 'RCurl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... /share/apps/anaconda2/bin/curl-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
Version has a libidn field
Version has CURLOPT_URL
Version has CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL
Version has CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE
Version has CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE
Version has CURLINFO_REQUEST_SIZE
Version has CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT
Version has CURLINFO_FILETIME
Version has CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD
Version has CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE
Version has CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT
Version has CURLINFO_PRIVATE
Version has CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE
Version has CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL
Version has CURLINFO_PROXYAUTH_AVAIL
Version has CURLINFO_OS_ERRNO
Version has CURLINFO_NUM_CONNECTS
Version has CURLINFO_SSL_ENGINES
Version has CURLINFO_COOKIELIST
Version has CURLINFO_LASTSOCKET
Version has CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH
Version has CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL
Version has CURLINFO_PRIMARY_IP
Version has CURLINFO_APPCONNECT_TIME
Version has CURLINFO_CERTINFO
Version has CURLINFO_CONDITION_UNMET
Version has CURLOPT_WRITEDATA
Version has CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD
Version has CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY
Version has CURLOPT_APPEND
Version has CURLOPT_KRBLEVEL
Version has CURLOPT_USE_SSL
Version has CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS
Version has CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS
Version has CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING
Version has CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING
Version has CURLOPT_NEW_FILE_PERMS
Version has CURLOPT_NEW_DIRECTORY_PERMS
Version has CURLOPT_POSTREDIR
Version has CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA
Version has CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS
Version has CURLOPT_PROXY_TRANSFER_MODE
Version has CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_SEEKDATA
Version has CURLOPT_CRLFILE
Version has CURLOPT_ISSUERCERT
Version has CURLOPT_ADDRESS_SCOPE
Version has CURLOPT_CERTINFO
Version has CURLOPT_USERNAME
Version has CURLOPT_PASSWORD
Version has CURLOPT_PROXYUSERNAME
Version has CURLOPT_PROXYPASSWORD
Version has CURLOPT_SSH_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_MD5
Version has CURLOPT_NOPROXY
Version has CURLOPT_TFTP_BLKSIZE
Version has CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_SERVICE
Version has CURLOPT_SOCKS5_GSSAPI_NEC
Version has CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS
Version has CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS
Version has CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES
Version has CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE
Version has CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE
Version has CURLOPT_FTP_SSL_CCC
Version has CURLOPT_COOKIELIST
Version has CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH
Version has CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP
Version has CURLOPT_FTP_FILEMETHOD
Version has CURLOPT_LOCALPORT
Version has CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE
Version has CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY
Version has CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_NETWORK_FUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_CONV_TO_NETWORK_FUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_CONV_FROM_UTF8_FUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE
Version has CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE
Version has CURLOPT_FTP_ALTERNATIVE_TO_USER
Version has CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION
Version has CURLOPT_SOCKOPTDATA
Version has CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE
libcurl version: libcurl 7.60.0
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/lib64/R/library/RCurl/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'RCurl' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/lib64/R/library/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/share/apps/R-distros/R-3.5.0/lib64/R/library/RCurl'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (re)installing packages on R 3.5.0.

My main problem was that it was not linked directly, and the conda-forge install was not successful.

So, I compiled directly from the source, by downloading ICU4C 58.2 from : http://site.icu-project.org/download

and compiled using make. Then, added the library location to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

After that, installing RCurl went through without a problem.